# Pass from a tab to another from a input type submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass from a tab to another tab through a input (type submit), that input has some JS code behind, but the console shows this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Registrarse</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
                <li role="presentation" class="active" id="pone">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#datospersonales">Datos personales</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" id="ptwo" class="disabled">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#registrousuario">Registro de usuario</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content mt-25">
                <div role="tabpanel" id="datospersonales" class="tab-pane active fade in">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="form1" name="form1">
                        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Nombres</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control s" placeholder="Nombres" id="name">
                        </div>

                        <label class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-1 control-label">Correo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control s" placeholder="Correo" id="email">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-11 col-md-1 mt-25">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" class="guardar" value="Siguiente" onclick="handleClick()">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var boton = document.querySelector(".guardar")
boton.addEventListener('click',handleClick);

function handleClick(){
    $('#myTabs a[href="#ptwo"]').tab('show');
}
```

I don't know if it's that i'm not using JQuery properly in this case, im new at this.

Comment: It seems like you are acessing the html elements before they are loaded. Is your script code placed within `head` or before closing `</body>` tag? Note - you are mixing javascript and jQuery. Stick with one, either use jquery or javascript.

Comment: also, you already added an `onclick` listener to the input on HTML code, why are you adding again on javascript? (I suggest to add only in JS)

Comment: @random before closing body tag and after head tag, but i cant put it somewhere else, this is a file from a server, and they just gave me this (blank files with include of header and footer)

Comment: @CalvinNunes thanks, I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found few things on your code, please consider this just observations.

> In the future please specify that you are using boostrap and jQuery (not all pages uses these frameworks), it will help to understand the issue that you are having , also please specify the version of the libraries that you are using!.
>
> in the Submit button you are repeating the attribute "class", so the second one will be ignored when you are trying to get by className; Other important point it since you are adding event handler through JS is not necessary to use "onclick".

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" class="guardar" value="Siguiente" onclick="handleClick()">
```

change by

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success guardar" value="Siguiente">
```

> The HTML submit button will handle a submit , it means that always will send the information in the page to other (could be the same), but that perform of sumit means another requests is done, so, it is necessary to be a submit button ?. Assuming the submit is needed you will need to prevent the event of sending the information (until you want that perform of information necessary), for preventing events you can use "event.preventDefault()", you also will need to add a logic to stop preventing when you consider the information is ready to be sent.
>
> the selector for the tab is not necessary to be to much specific, since is supossed that the id af an HTML element should not be the same in the entire page.

```
var boton = document.querySelector(".guardar")
boton.addEventListener('click',handleClick);

function handleClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#ptwo').tab('show');
}
```

this is the sample workiing:

[Your sample working](https://codepen.io/edmret/pen/OJPEzeX)

Comment: It still shows the same "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: @h0merr did you try the sample that I put on the CodePen?, also as other users commented try to put your JS code at the end of the <body> tag, maybe finally this is just the ordering of your code :).